# can't instantiate instance of exported custom module Nodejs, that extends EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, class, instantiation, extend, eventemitter

community. 
I can't instantiate instance of exported custom module Nodejs.

I have 2 files:    one custom test module "resource.js"  and "ext-emitter.js"

in resource.js  create class of Resource and extend it from EventEmitter class.

```
    // resource.js
    var util = require("util");
    var eventEmitterInstance = require("events").EventEmitter;


function Resource(m){
    this.maxEvents = m;
    var self = this;

    process.nextTick(function() {
       var count = 0;
       self.emit('start');
       var t = setInterval(function(){
          self.emit('data', ++count);
          if (count === m) {
              self.emit('end', count);
              clearInterval(t);
          }

       }, 10);
    });

}

util.inherits(Resource, eventEmitterInstance);
module.exports = Resource();
```

Then I import the module above in the next file   ext-emitter.js
I try to instantiate extended custom module Resource() (which in its turn extends EventEmitter class), but I got an error:
 " 'Resource' is not defined"

Please help me find the place where I went wrong.

```
var r = require("./resource");

var r = new Resource(7);

r.on('start', function(){
    console.log("I've started the resource getting process!!!");
});

r.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log("I received this data --> " + d );
});

r.on('end', function(finalCountOfRes){
   console.log("I have finished resource getting. The num of res gotten: " + finalCountOfRes); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the place where you went wrong was the first line in file "ext-emitter.js"
Just be more careful, you could've spotted the mistake yourself:
Here you require your custom module "resource.js" and placing it to a variable "r", then you're instantiating new instance of imported module with the same variable "r" and calling new on unknown/undefined within ext-emitter.js   Resource() object.

```
var r = require("./resource");
var r = new Resource(7);
```

Just keep your eye on var names. 
Change the first line on:

```
var Resource = require("./resource");
```

And it will work just fine.

Comment: ok the undefined error is gone. 
Now when running it says: /home/ubuntu/workspace/node.js/ext-emitter.js:3                                                                                                               
var r = new Resource(7);                                                                                                                                      
        ^                                                                                                                                                     
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: in second file  resource.js   the last line when you export, get rid of redundant parentheses  like this: module.exports = Resource;